# iOS Method Method Swizzling - 2 SDK trying to Swizzle "ViewDidAppear" method in 1 app, then what will happen?

Tags: ios, methods, swizzling, method-swizzling

If I add 2 SDKs in my iOS app, which inside doing method swizzling for same method "ViewDidAppear" then what could (good + bad) be happened at runtime.

Comment: More importantly, how would you find out if these SDK's are both swizzling?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on swizzling approach, few different scenarios possible:

1. Infinite recursion - stack overflow
2. The latter swizzled implementation will be used
3. Some kind of chain of responsibility is built